# DRY-ing up ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I've got multiple resources in my ActiveAdmin installation that share quite a lot of the same traits, like:

- The same or similar scopes
- Equal or similar controller methods (action_methods, for example)
- Similar attributes (with code blocks) in the show action
- Similar attributes (with code blocks) in the edit action

What is the best way to avoid duplicating this functionality across the different resources?

I have set up decorators to avoid duplicating functionality in the index view, but I'm not sure if (and how?) this could be used in the other cases.

Comment: Have you looked at using concerns? http://richonrails.com/articles/rails-4-code-concerns-in-active-record-models

Comment: I am familiar with common patterns to DRY things up in regular ruby (and rails) code, but I've got no idea how to tie it into ActiveAdmin and its syntax. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend the DSL with monkey patch:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  # This is the class where all the register blocks are evaluated.
  class ResourceDSL < DSL
    def your_custom_method attr
      #common code
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can use your_custom_method in your registered resource file.

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_dsl.rb

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I was waiting to see if anyone else had other suggestions and then forgot about it for while. So this is really the best way to do it? Ouch.

Answer (score 6):

You can also `extend` your module. For example:

```
module AccountManageable
  def has_manageable_account 
    permit_params :name, :email, :role, :avatar

    filter :name, as: :string
    filter :email, as: :string

    # ... other DSL methods
  end
end
```

and then in your admin

```
ActiveAdmin.register Admin do
  extend AccountManageable

  has_manageable_account
end
```